# OpenGL ES 1.0 Android -- Drawing More Advanced Shapes

Tags: android, opengl-es

So, I'm currently trying to learn OpenGL ES for Android as a part of a project I'm undergoing for a Mobile Programming class. I wanted to make a quick basic 3D game in which the user rotates a "gun" and has to shoot targets under a certain time limit. The problem I am running into is designing my Target shapes.

I want the target shapes to be a basic diamond gem shape. 
I have read the android developer guide for drawing out Pyramids/Cubes with vertices and indices describing the shapes vectors and face's to be drawn, but I am having a lot of trouble getting my desired shape.

Here is my Target's Vertices and Indices

```
float[] vertices = 
{ 
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, //0. Back Right
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 1. Back Left
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // 2. Top
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, //3. Front Right
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, // 4. Front Left
    0.0f, -2.0f, 1.0f //5. Bottom
};
byte[] indices = 
{ 
    3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3, //draw front face
    0, 2, 4, 5, 4, 0, // draw right face
    1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 1, // draw back face
    3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3 // draw left
}; // end byte[] indices
```

Here in the indices I'm trying to draw the top face, than the bottom face, and wrap around my shape in a counter clock wise manner, starting from the front and moving to the right, back and then left respectively. Yet, with this I get a shape that looks like an old Star Fox ship. I've looked for help before, but couldn't find much of anything that helped me, either through my understanding or it was a similar question but about shaders or textures.

I guess my question would be how do you properly apply the drawing for such a shape? I have tried many Counter Clock Wise attempts that always led me to the weirdest shapes. I don't think I'm fully understanding how the indices are drawn in order. I would post some pics, but I'm new to Stackoverflow >.>

Thank you to all help in advance.

Comment: What primitive type are you using (first argument of `glDrawElements`)? Is it `GL_TRIANGLES`? I can take a look later today if nobody else jumps in. Will take some sketching on paper...

Comment: Yes, it is GL_TRIANGLES. I haven't messed around with any of the others yet, still wanting to get my basics down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indices look somewhat mixed up. Based on my sketch, you mainly have vertex 3 and 4 swapped in the index array. You can tell that it can't be quite right because vertex 3 is commented "Front Right", but it does not show up in the indices under "right face". Vice versa for vertex 4.  Most of the triangles are clockwise.

The comments are somewhat misleading. The x-axis is normally drawn left to right. You have the vertices with negative x-coordinates labelled "right", and the ones with positive x-coordinates labelled "left", which seems unusual.

I wonder if you might have used a left-handed coordinate system for your definitions, which would explain much of the above. Make sure that you always use a right-handed coordinate system, and look at the winding order from the outside of the object.

Did you mean to place vertex 5 under the center of the square, or is the y-offset intentional? I moved it under the center in the code below, but you can move it to where you had it without changing the topology.

Based on my paper sketch, the correct version would look something like this (untested):

```
float[] vertices = 
{ 
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, //0. Back Left
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 1. Back Right
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // 2. Top
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, //3. Front Left
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, // 4. Front Right
    0.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f //5. Bottom
};
byte[] indices = 
{ 
    3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, //draw front face
    0, 3, 2, 5, 3, 0, // draw left face
    1, 5, 0, 2, 1, 0, // draw back face
    4, 1, 2, 5, 1, 4 // draw right
};
```

Comment: So, thanks for the reply, I should definitely make sure my code is proper first off. Yes, I meant it to be like you have it and I didn't even realize that my Left and Right were in reverse. That could help fix a lot of my confusion. 

I don't know if my drawings were off because of my vertex's were off or if I didn't properly understand the drawing order for indices, but I really appreciate your reply and will sketch it out on paper to better understand it all.

Comment: Reto Koradi, I was wondering if you could further explain how you got your paper sketch? I'm working on getting a further complex shape down (a "gun") and what I've sketched myself based on how I understand indices and the vertices the object should come out correct. However only 7 vertices of my 22 are drawn, I don't know if this is do to how I drew the indices or the GL_TRIANGLES or something else. Thank you.

Comment: I don't really have any magic recipes. It was a back of the envelope (literally) sketch. I draw a 3D coordinate system, with the x-axis going right, y-axis up, and z-axis towards me. Kind of like this, except not as pretty: https://wiki.brown.edu/confluence/display/wdm/3D+Coordinate+System. Then I draw points, label them with their indices, and collect the triangles. CCW for the triangles facing me, CW for the triangles facing away. I have never built very complex shapes manually. Most of what I have done was analytic shapes (geometric and spline type surfaces).